# webView.loadRequest error if use presentViewController, but if use segue all is ok

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, webview

i just arrived to Swift ...

I have a View Controller with a button that "segue" to Second View Controller.

This Second View Controller have a WebView.

If i press this button, everything its ok, and i load the second view controller with website inside.

Problem is because sometimes i will need force this segue manually. Then i do this:

```
   let secondViewController:WebV = WebV()
   self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And then, it produced follow error in line *"webView.loadRequest(request)"*

Error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you just performSegueWithIdentifier?  On your storyboards,create a segue to the second view controller and give it an identifier in your inspector, i.e. ("mySegueIdentifier") -- than when you need to segue just call performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueIdentifier")

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried. Code run without error but second view not start.  I give the name in "storyboard segue/identifier" (class empty and module is empty too). Do i need anything else?

Comment: The second viewController needs to have the same class name as the file.  For example, if you created a second view controller called secondViewController and it's a UIViewController, you need to create a new file (class) to control secondViewController. Then under class name dropdown, there should be an option for that file (class).  Pick that and you should be good to go.  Try to print something to the terminal from the new file to verify it's working.  then performSegueWithIdentifier("mySeguieIdentifier", sender: self) should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your help. I had classes as you tell me, but i found the reason... I use performSegueWithIdentifier on viewDidLoad and i'm reading that i need call like this dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueWeb", sender: self)}. Thanks again